# Overwrite property of extended class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a class that I am not allowed to modify:

```
export default abstract class Class1 {
  private pausePerIteration = 1000;

  constructor (protected readonly logger: LoggerService) {
    super();
  }
```

and I'm extending it into another class, the goal is to overwrite the property `pausePerIteration`

```
class Class2 extends Class1 {

    constructor (
        protected readonly logger: LoggerService,
        pausePerIteration: any;
    ) {
        super(logger,pausePerIteration);
    }
```

but since it is private, it can't be overwritten

Comment: I couldn't find a clean dupetarget for this question, but I have a strong sense there must be one. If anyone finds it, would you @ ping me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a word: **Don't**. The class doesn't provide any way to do it, so that member isn't part of that class's public contract, at all. The member could go away in the next update to that class, or change meaning, etc.; its exact value could be important to the class implementation; and so on. In any of a dozen ways, trying to reach in and muck about with it is a Bad Idea™. :-) Fundamentally, it's private **for a reason**. Don't try to bypass that.

It's *possible* to do it, because unlike JavaScript's private members, TypeScript private members aren't really private:

```
super(logger);
// @ts-ignore
this.pausePerIteration = someOtherValue;
```

...but **I strongly recommend you don't,** not least because it's entirely possible the class could be updated to use a JavaScript private member instead, and then you'd be back to Square One because that kind of back door doesn't exist for those.